# Connect to master table in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have two tables Donors and districts. I am using yii2 and pretty new to this. I want to connect my donor table to district table in order to display  district name in the list.

i am using `ActiveDataProvider` and please see the code below.

```
$query = \app\models\Donors::find()
            ->joinWith(['donorDistrict'])
            ->where(['districts.district_id' => 'donors.district_id'])
            ->all();
```

and in donors

```
public function getDonorDistrict() 
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Districts::className(), ['district_id' => 'district_id'])->via('donorDistrict');
    }
```

Unfortunately, this is not working. Can someone tell me where i went wrong ?

Comment: Share examples of your table structures. And show your expectations regarding an array that you want to get in return.